# XAMPP MySQL shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

XAMPP MySQL shuts down unexpectedly. I was trying to enable the configuration storage settings earlier, turned my PC off, and returned to this.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled XAMPP within the past couple of days, changed port numbers to apache and setup a password.

I've deleted the ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and the ib_logfile1 files, and changes the port numbers to the my.ini and php.ini files.

Help would be appreciated.

```
2015-11-10 17:40:54 418 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151110 17:40:54 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
151110 17:40:54 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
151110 17:40:54 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
151110 17:40:54 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
151110 17:40:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151110 17:40:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151110 17:40:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
151110 17:40:54 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151110 17:40:54 [ERROR] Aborting

151110 17:40:54 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: just for a reference for future, this solution helped me when nothing else worked! : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cD4XO9Pj1s